# Updating job status on SauceLabs via Jenkins Sauce on Demand not working

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, saucelabs

Below is my code. It was working fine and i was able to see saucelab videos and pass/fail result on jenkins earlier. but now somehow its not working and i am not able to see videos and pass/fail result on jenkin.

```
public void UpdateResults(boolean testResults)
{
    SauceREST saucerest = new SauceREST(USERNAME,ACCESS_KEY);
    Map<String,Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    updates.put("passed", testResults);
    saucerest.updateJobInfo(getSessionId(),updates);
}

@After()
public void tierDown()
{
    driver.get().quit();
    UpdateResults(testResults);
    String message = String.format("SauceOnDemandSessionID=%1$s job- 
 name=%2$s",sessionId.get(),jobName);
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Comment: Are there any error logs you could provide?

Comment: @tellob Thank you for your response. However it was issue with jenkins plugin. It got solved now.